# php In _array not working correctly with this code

Tags: php

For some reason, I cannot get the in_array function to work properly with this code. I want to check to see if a specific number is in the array returned back from the database. So I passed it into the in_array function but it is still returning false even when I add or remove quotations around the number.

```
    <?php 

     include('connection.php');

     $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT sku FROM inventory");

     $arr = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       $arr[] = $row;

       //echo $row['sku']. "<br>";
   }

     //echo $arr[0]['sku'];

        print_r($arr);

   if(in_array(12345678, $arr[0], TRUE)){
       echo "here";
    }else{
      echo "not here";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: You're only checking the first row. Maybe it's in a different row.

Comment: Any reason you don't put the check in the query? `SELECT sku FROM inventory WHERE sku = 12345678`

Comment: You're using `in_array` in strict mode (third arg), and `mysqli_fetch_array` returns strings. Can't work. But yeah, if you're only checking if the value is present in the table, no need for this.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'm probably thinking of PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the array to complicated for `in_array()` If you make it a single dimension array rather than a multi dimension array it will work.

```
<?php 

include('connection.php');

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT sku FROM inventory");

$arr = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $arr[] = $row['sku'];
}

print_r($arr);

if(in_array('12345678', $arr)){
    echo "here";
}else{
    echo "not here";
}
?>
```

Comment: wow, thanks! I had no idea it was the $arr = array() that was causing the problem! I couldn't figure out why my array was coming out multidimensional

Comment: It was not the `$arr = array()` that was causing the problem it was the `$arr[] = $row;` that was causing the problem. That was building a multidimentional array and `in_array()` wont work on that

Comment: ahh, I see. By not defining $row['SKU']; correct? I've only been learning PHP with a purpose for about 2 weeks. I've dabbled here and there but never took it serious.